# Epitesi di -ne: dove si dà questo fenomeno?

Tags: regional

In una discussione a proposito del canto XVIII dell'*Inferno* con un gruppo di persone, ricordo che un fiorentino spiegò che il fenomeno dell'epitesi di -*ne* per alcuni monosillabi accentati e per alcune parole tronche si può ancora sentire da qualche parte della Toscana. Credo fosse in campagna, non in città.

Mi riferisco al passo in cui Virgilio annuncia l'arrivo di Giasone, in cui si trova il verbo "féne" (che sta per *fe'*) con l'epitesi di -*ne*:

> E 'l buon maestro, sanza mia dimanda, 
>                 mi disse: «Guarda quel grande che vene, 
>                 e per dolor non par lagrime spanda:   84 
>   
>                 quanto aspetto reale ancor ritene! 
>                
>   Quelli è Iasón, che per cuore e per senno 
>                 li Colchi del monton privati féne.   87

Per mia sorpresa, sfogliando il libro *L'italiano nelle regioni: Roma e il Lazio* di Pietro Trifone ([[1](https://www.academia.edu/15932159/Roma_e_il_Lazio_intero_volume_1_?auto=download)] e [[2](https://www.academia.edu/15954140/Roma_e_il_Lazio_intero_volume_2_?auto=download)]), mi sono imbattuta in una spiegazione dei fenomeni fono-morfologici più caratteristici del romanesco di Giuseppe Gioachino Belli, tra cui, a pagina 67, si trova questo:

> l'epitesi di -*ne*, cui Belli ricorre 
>   soprattutto in rima (nei monosillabi accentati come *dine* 'dire', *none* 'no', *quane* 'qua', *tene* 'te' e in qualche polisillabo ossitono)

Immagino che *dine* veramente corrisponda a *di'*.

Non avevo idea che questo fenomeno fosse stato presente anche nel romanesco. Si può riscontrare ancora oggi da qualche parte nel Lazio? In generale, dove si può sentire questa epitesi di -*ne*, se veramente è ancora viva nell'attualità?

Comment: Come romano, posso dire che ne ho presente l'uso attuale solo in “sìne” e “nòne”, usati talvolta in modo scherzosi come rafforzativi, per lo più come a dire “Sì [no], te l'ho già detto tante volte!”, e rarissimamente con avverbi come “qua” e “là”, sempre ad accennare un tono stizzito.

Comment: Se può interessare, posso riportare la voce in proposito del _Dizionario romanesco_ di Fernando Ravaro, che parla per lo più dell'uso in Belli e prima, ma conclude: “In qualche parola tronca del linguaggio familiare più popolare si può trovare ancora al presente traccia dell'esistenza della particella eufonica: méne - téne - quìne - làne - perchéne - sìne - nòne, ecc.”

Comment: Ho appena trovato questa [voce del Treccani sulla sillaba epitetica -*ne*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ne_res-28ed7ac9-0027-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/) in cui si afferma «ancor oggi nell’uso pop. di alcune regioni centr. e merid. (Toscana, Umbria, Lazio, Marche, Abruzzo, e, nella forma -*ni*, in Calabria e Sicilia)».

Answer (score 2):

Questa non è una risposta compiuta, ma è troppo lunga per essere un commento e forse può avere qualche utilità. Il *Dizionario romanesco* di Fernando Ravaro (Newton Compton) alla voce “ne” riporta:

> **ne** - Particella enclitica, con valore eufonico che nel romanesco, almeno sino alla metà del 1800 (per quanto se ne può dedurre dai testi disponibili) era consuetudine aggiungere a tutte le parole tronche ed ai monosillabi accentati, quasi come un addolcimento del loro suono brusco, evidentemente poco accetto, similmemte a quanto avviene anche nel dialetto toscano che alle finali accentate usa aggiungere una "e" eufonica (sìe, nòe, giùe, ecc.). Di tale caratteristica, oggi quasi totalmente scomparsa, è agevole rilevare la presenza generalizzata negli autori antecedenti al Belli, quantunque anche questi talora ne abbia fatto uso. È infatti presente nella *Vita di Cola di Rienzo*: cioè - ène - sìne; nel Codice Vaticano 7654: ène; nel Bernini: chìne - vorràne - consigliàne; nel Castelletti: dìe [*sic: forse un refuso per dìne*] - ène - làne - sìne - stàne. In particolare Benedetto Micheli, nelle sue opere, ne fa sistematica norma, talché è difficile trovare una parola tronca, specialmente le voci verbali, che ne sia priva. || MICHELI - Che ve dole? Se sa, voio cantàne - Che, come penza, facile non ène - D'archibbuscio; ma poi, quanno ch'è line || Ecco alcuni esempi tratti dal Belli || E padron Chiappa m'arispose: Nòne - È propio tempo mo questo che quìne - Er zor Stramoni che me visitòne - Eppuro sto gustaccio che c'è mòne || In qualche parola tronca del linguaggio familiare più popolare si può trovare ancora al presente traccia dell'esistenza della particella eufonica: "méne" - "téne" - "quìne" - "làne" - "perchéne" - "sìne"- "nòne", ecc.

Personalmente, come ho già scritto in un commento, in quanto romano, posso dire che ne ho presente l'uso attuale solo in “sìne” e “nòne”, usati talvolta in modo scherzoso come rafforzativi, per lo più come a dire “Sì [no], te l'ho già detto tante volte!”, e rarissimamente con avverbi come “qua” e “là”, sempre ad accennare un tono stizzito.

Comment: Grazie, @DaG! Ho anche trovato qualcosa [qui](http://roma.andreapollett.com/S8/dialett5.htm), ma non so quanta credibilità possa avere questa fonte.

Comment: Adesso ho visto su *Ragazzi di vita* di Pasolini: "«Che, n'ho già fatti pochi de anni a bottega!» «Indovve, a Porta Portese, che?» fece il Caciotta. «Sìne», disse Amerigo." E anche: "«None», gridò il Caciotta" o "«Che fai er barista, fai?» «Sìne»". L'avevo letto molti anni fa, ma non me ne ricordavo.